# Restore from backup after Installation

Tags: backup

I made a Hard Reset in my mobile and mistakenly avoided the restore session while it asked me to restore or start afresh. I have my backups in Onedrive. . Is there any way I can restore it now. .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. I've never seen any kind of way to restore from a backup AFTER a reset of the phone.

You'll have to do all the reset process again and try not to miss the "restore" part